# Websphere MQ - how to get currently used certificate details by MQ queue manager

Tags: ssl, ibm-mq

Its known that the queue manager properties give the location for the ssl keystore files that the queue manager is currently using.
However is there a way to get the certificate details like cert serial, expiry etc that is been CURRENTLY used by the queue manager.

openssl and gsk comands query and give only the certificate details in the ssl keystore. However,

Am asking this because, suppose if there is a certificate renewal happenned and suppose if there is NOT a refresh (refresh security type(ssl)) done at MQ, then it would only have the old certificate details in it.

So I need a command or script where I can get the output as the currently used certificate details by the queue manager. Please assist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use openssl to query the host and port for the certificate details currently being returned.

For example:

```
echo -n | openssl s_client -connect dnsname.domain.com:port 2>&1 | openssl x509 -noout -issuer -subject -dates
```

This will return something like the following where issuer and subject will be the full DN values. notAfter is the expiration date of the cert.

```
issuer= /C=....
subject= /C=....
notBefore=Nov  1 13:45:35 2020 GMT
notAfter=Nov  1 13:45:34 2021 GMT
```

Comment: `openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -showcerts` this one throws below error, I substituted the qmgr port 2414 and host as localhost **connect: Connection refused connect:errno=79** have executed this cmd as mq admin

Comment: 79 is just "Connection refused".  Are you sure you are specifying the correct host and port?  Can you test with `curl -v telnet://localhost:2414`. Is it possible that your listener does not listen on localhost,  display it and check for the `IPADDR` setting.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is functionality exactly what you are asking for.

You could determine what certificate your queue manager should be using by looking at the certificate label set in the QMGR CERTLABL setting and then using that in openssl/gsk commands to query the keystore. For example:

In MQSC:

```
DISPLAY QMGR CERTLABL
```

on the command line:

```
runmqakm -cert -details -db <keystore> -stashed -label <label from above>
```

However, that will show the certificate in the keystore and if you've started TLS connections and then modified the keystore contents you could potentially have a difference between what the keystore contains and what MQ is currently using. The above also doesn't take into account different certificates being used on a per-channel basis.

You could use openssl to query the queue manager listener which would return the certificate it is using by connecting to the queue manager. This will cause an error because MQ won't understand why openssl just connected to it and then instantly disconnected:

```
openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -showcerts
```

This should give a lot of information about the certificate currently in use. If you want to query a certificate in use by a particular channel then you would need to work out the correct SNI to send using this documentation page: https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-websphere-mq-how-does-mq-provide-multiple-certificates-certlabl-capability

If these don't meet your needs of having a MQ command you can run to print out the certificate details currently in use without querying the keystore on the disk then i would encourage you to raise a feature request with the IBM MQ team: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=changeRequestLanding&PROD_ID=520

Comment: MQ 7 is being used so unable to use CERTLABL (MQv8 onwards)

`openssl s_client -connect <host>:<port> -showcerts
`
this one throws below error, I substituted the qmgr port 2414 and host as localhost
**connect: Connection refused
connect:errno=79**
have executed this cmd as mq admin

Comment: what I believe is if queue manager maintains a copy and checks it against each incoming connection, there should be a way to retrieve it.
Because everytime it takes it own cert copy to validate rather it doesnt go to the keystore everytime for validation

Comment: As JoshMC says above. 79 is connection refused. Have you supplied the queue manager's hostname and port in place of <host> and <port> in the above. For example if i'm running it on the machine my queue manager is on and the MQ listener is set to 1414 i would run `openssl s_client -connect localhost:1414`

Comment: Yes it worked, have tried the below and got the required output.
Also keytool utility can be used for windows

AIX/Linux:

`echo | openssl s_client -connect <QMServerName>:<QMPort> -showcerts 2>&1 | openssl x509 -noout -dates`




Windows:

`C:\Windows\system32>"C:\Program Files\IBM\Java70\jre\bin\keytool" -printcert -sslserver <QMServerName>:<QMPort>`